# How do I filter extensions to files that are uploaded or posted to php webserver?

Tags: c#, php

I made a post function from c# to send a file to the webserver (php), every file that was uploaded was not filtered by the extension, I was afraid that if there were bad people uploading malicious files such as webshells or other malware into my web server.
I only want one extension (.lic) that can be uploaded via the "post" function

```
(php)
<?php
$uploads_dir = './newfolder';
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
?>

c#
public void upLoad()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string myFile = this.temPfold + "License.lic";
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.UploadFile(this.myurl, "POST", myFile);
            client.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not really solve your security concerns I guess. Just because a file has a ".jpg" extension for example does not mean it actually contains an image

Comment: `$ext = strrchr('somefile.php', '.');`  returns `'.php'`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7b389be195b3694e668b9855c12867c8b12a696)  So in your case `if(strrchr($_FILES["file"]["name"], '.') == '.lic') //process the file`  This will return the last extension, but as mentioned just because a file says it;s something doesn't mean it is.

Comment: You can  use the function mime_content_type() for checking mime-type of uploaded file. [MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: Info about extension and mime-type of file in POST-request may be forgery, so do not trust them. ```mime_content_type($file)``` returns **real** mime-type of uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it was pointed out in a comment - just because a file purports to be of a particular extension does not mean that it necessarily is of that type. However some filtering can be achieved by doing some processing like the following. Test for extension expected mimetype, size and if each `.lic` file has a similar header you can test a portion of the actual file itself - though perhaps  a file `sha1` or `md5` checksum might be of use too.

```
<?php

    try{
        if( !empty( $_FILES['file'] ) ){

            $LIC_MIME_TYPE='text/plain';    # what is the correct mimetype?
            $LIC_MAX_FILE_SIZE=1024;        # how large???
            $dir = './newfolder/';

            $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
            $name=$obj->name;
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $err=$obj->error;
            $size=$obj->size;
            $mime=mime_content_type( $tmp );


            if( !empty( $err ) )throw new Exception('An error occurred', $err );
            if( !$mime==$LIC_MIME_TYPE )throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Invalid mimetype %s',$mime),400 );

            $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
            if( $ext!=='lic' ) throw new Exception('Invalid file extension',400 );
            if( !is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ) throw new Exception( 'Possible File upload attack', 400 );
            if( $size > $LIC_MAX_FILE_SIZE ) throw new Exception( 'File too large', 400 );

            $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $dir . $name );
            if( !$status )throw new Exception('Failed to Save file',400 );

        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( sprintf( '%s [%d]', $e->getMessage(),$e->getCode() ) );
    }
?>
```